# Akka HTTP Connection Pool Hangs After Couple of Hours

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have an HTTP Connection Pool that hangs after a couple of hours of running:

```
private def createHttpPool(host: String): SourceQueue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])] = {
    val pool = Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[Promise[HttpResponse]](host)
    Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](config.poolBuffer, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
      .via(pool).toMat(Sink.foreach {
        case ((Success(res), p)) => p.success(res)
        case ((Failure(e), p)) => p.failure(e)
      })(Keep.left).run
  }
```

I enqueue items with:

```
private def enqueue(uri: Uri): Future[HttpResponse] = {
    val promise = Promise[HttpResponse]
    val request = HttpRequest(uri = uri) -> promise

    queue.offer(request).flatMap {
      case Enqueued => promise.future
      case _ => Future.failed(ConnectionPoolDroppedRequest)
    }
}
```

And resolve the response like this:

```
private def request(uri: Uri): Future[HttpResponse] = {
    def retry = {
      Thread.sleep(config.dispatcherRetryInterval)
      logger.info(s"retrying")
      request(uri)
    }

    logger.info("req-start")
    for {
      response <- enqueue(uri)

      _ = logger.info("req-end")

      finalResponse <- response.status match {
        case TooManyRequests => retry
        case OK => Future.successful(response)
        case _ => response.entity.toStrict(10.seconds).map(s => throw Error(s.toString, uri.toString))
      }
    } yield finalResponse
}
```

The result of this function is then always transformed if the Future is successful:

```
def get(uri: Uri): Future[Try[JValue]] = {
  for {
    response <- request(uri)
    json <- Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Try[JValue]]
  } yield json
}
```

Everything works fine for a while and then all I see in the logs are req-start and no req-end.

My akka configuration is like this:

```
akka {
  actor.deployment.default {
    dispatcher = "my-dispatcher"
  }
}

my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"

  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 256
    parallelism-factor = 128.0
    parallelism-max = 1024
  }
}

akka.http {
  host-connection-pool {
    max-connections = 512
    max-retries = 5
    max-open-requests = 16384
    pipelining-limit = 1
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a configuration problem or a code problem. I have my parallelism and connection numbers so high because without it I get very poor req/s rate (I want to request as fast possible - I have other rate limiting code to protect the server).

Answer (score 3):

You are not consuming the entity of the responses you get back from the server. Citing the docs below:

> Consuming (or discarding) the Entity of a request is mandatory! If
>   accidentally left neither consumed or discarded Akka HTTP will assume
>   the incoming data should remain back-pressured, and will stall the
>   incoming data via TCP back-pressure mechanisms. A client should
>   consume the Entity regardless of the status of the HttpResponse.

The entity comes in the form of a `Source[ByteString, _]` which needs to be run to avoid resource starvation.

If you don't need to read the entity, the simplest way to consume the entity bytes is to discard them, by using

```
res.discardEntityBytes()
```

(you can attach a callback by adding - e.g. - `.future().map(...)`).

[This page in the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html) describes all the alternatives to this, including how to read the bytes if needed.

--- EDIT

After more code/info was provided, it is clear that the resource consumption is not the problem. There is another big red flag in this implementation, namely the `Thread.sleep` in the retry method.
This is a blocking call that is very likely to starve the threading infrastructure of your underlying actor system.

A full blown explanation of why this is dangerous was provided in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.3/scala/http/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html).

Try changing that and using `akka.pattern.after` ([docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#After)). Example below:

```
def retry = akka.pattern.after(200 millis, using = system.scheduler)(request(uri))
```

Comment: I actually do consume the entity after I get the response. I'll update the post with some more information.

Comment: Just changed my code to use akka.pattern.after and will post an update if the issue occurs again.

I did profile the earlier Thread.sleep code though, and the profiler showed that none of the threads are sleeping when it stops working.  Whenever I get a 429, jvisualvm shows that one of the threads is sleeping for about 500ms and then that thread starts running again so I'm a little skeptical using the scheduler will fix it. Nevertheless, using Thread.sleep was really bad - thanks for giving me a good solution to fix that.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. This is the thread dump: https://gist.github.com/pradyuman/bf83a8f3a293d8c679fcb6dc5f566a80