# akka-Http post request hangs on Expect: 100-continue

Tags: scala, http, akka-http

I am encountering an unexpected behaviour in akka-http POST request endpoint, which  sends the payload of around 40kb. After `8-9 times` the request hangs with the response

```
> Host: localhost:9090
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 1726
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
```

On looking for solution I tried the request adding `-H 'Expect:'`, upon which the request hangs with response

```
> POST /xstreams/v1/submitJob HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.xxx.xx.xx:9090
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 42464
> 
* upload completely sent off: 42464 out of 42464 bytes
```

I am not able to find the root cause, whether it be due to some backpressure created 
PS: The request is made at interval of 30 min and hangs after 8-9 times and works after the services is restarted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481876/akka-http-connection-pool-hangs-after-couple-of-hours

Comment: Can you share your Github Code link?

Answer (score 0):

Your application might run out of available threads. Have you tried to see what 
 threads are doing when you get a `Done waiting for 100-continue` ?